# why mulsd does not multiply xmm* registers

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64

Was writing function computing distance between two points in three-dimensional space. gdb session:

```
48      mulsd   xmm1, xmm0
(gdb) p/f $xmm0
$5 = {v4_float = {5.08412027, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {5.3576676113063418e-315, 0}, v16_int8 = {29, -79, -94, 64, 0 <repeats 12 times>}, v8_int16 = {-20195, 16546, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0}, v4_int32 = {5.08412027, 0, 0, 0}, v2_int64 = {5.3576676113063418e-315, 0}, uint128 = 3.9528689422358843932327897004554155e-4942}
(gdb) p/f $xmm1
$6 = {v4_float = {5.08412027, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {5.3576676113063418e-315, 0}, v16_int8 = {29, -79, -94, 64, 0 <repeats 12 times>}, v8_int16 = {-20195, 16546, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0}, v4_int32 = {5.08412027, 0, 0, 0}, v2_int64 = {5.3576676113063418e-315, 0}, uint128 = 3.9528689422358843932327897004554155e-4942}
(gdb) n
49      movsd   xmm0, xmm2
(gdb) p/f $xmm1
$7 = {v4_float = {0, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {0, 0}, v16_int8 = {0 <repeats 16 times>}, v8_int16 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, v4_int32 = {0, 0, 0, 0}, v2_int64 = {0, 0}, 
  uint128 = 0}
(gdb) p/f $xmm0
$8 = {v4_float = {5.08412027, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {5.3576676113063418e-315, 0}, v16_int8 = {29, -79, -94, 64, 0 <repeats 12 times>}, v8_int16 = {-20195, 16546, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0}, v4_int32 = {5.08412027, 0, 0, 0}, v2_int64 = {5.3576676113063418e-315, 0}, uint128 = 3.9528689422358843932327897004554155e-4942}
```

Oddly got zero in destination register.
Do you have any suggestions how to perform multiplication without getting zero's?

Comment: Are those things really meant to be `double`s? 5.3576676113063418e-315 is ridiculously small (subnormal in fact)

Comment: I filled memory with values `random` gave and then moved that resulting values to xmm* registers. I think any sequence of bits will result in valid double.

Comment: It's valid, but its square is zero.

Comment: Why? Is it result of "rounding" because of limited precision?

Comment: No, it's due to underflow, which is a result of limited exponent range.

Comment: If it is underflow, why programs gives 0 but not large number?

Comment: Use `p $xmm0.v2_double` to print just the `double` interpretation of xmm0.  It's a lot less noisy on screen.  Also, you should use MOVAPD (or MOVAPS) to copy between registers.  Only use MOVSD if you want to merge with the upper element of the destination register.

Comment: underflow:  x^2 is *closer* to zero for x<1.  Squaring a number makes it farther away from 1.  Testing FP math with random garbage values is not a good idea until you're sure you know what the instructions do with "regular" values like 3.14159...

Comment: @Peter, write as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get zero because of underflow.  x^2 is *closer* to zero for x<1. Squaring a number makes it farther away from 1.

5.3e-315 has smaller magnitude than `sqrt(smallest denormal double)`, so squaring it results in a zero.  (Note that `DBL_MIN` is the smallest normalized positive double, but denormals can be smaller.)

Testing FP math with random garbage values is not a good idea until you're sure you know what the instructions do with "regular" values like 3.14159...  FP math is hard enough already:

> [Floating-point] math is hard.
>
> You just won’t believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly hard it is. I mean, you may think it’s difficult to calculate when trains from Chicago and Los Angeles will collide, but that’s just peanuts to floating-point math.
>
> -- Bruce Dawson's excellent [series of articles on tricky FP math stuff](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

---

Use `p $xmm0.v2_double` to print just the double interpretation of `xmm0`. It's a lot less noisy on screen.

---

Also, you should use MOVAPD (or MOVAPS) to copy between registers. Only use MOVSD if you want to merge with the upper element of the destination register.